# jQuery Datatable on click tr function fires multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I select a row on the table, then click my "Add row" button, one row is added. I then click on another row, then click "Add row", it adds two rows. Every time I click on another row, the number of rows added goes up as well. How do I make it so only one row is added every time?

I'm pretty sure its due to a click event inside of another click event but I'm not sure how to fix that issue.

My current event adding rows:

```
$(document).on('click', 'tr', function() {
    var t = $('#data-table').DataTable();
    $('#data-table').dataTable();


    $('#addbtn').on( 'click', function () {
        t.row.add( [ 
            'New Group'
         ] ).draw( false );

    } );

} );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'tr', function() {
 var t = $('#data-table').DataTable();
 $('#data-table').dataTable();


 $('#addbtn').on( 'click', function () {
    t.row.add( [ 
        'New Group'
     ] ).draw( false );
    //This removes the listener when you are done with it
    //And it will create another when you click again
    $( "#addbtn").off( "click" );

 });
});
```

or you could basically move that `addbtn` listener out of `tr` listener
Hope these work!

Comment: Hmmm, still having the same problem unfortunately

Comment: I have updated the code would you use     $( "#addBtn").detach( "click" );
instead

Comment: No change unfortunately.

Comment: or this $('#addBtn').off('click'); I am looking through jQuery document sorry for mistakes

Comment: No worries, I appreciate the help anyway! Still having same problem with off.

Comment: I made typo did you fix it

Comment: Ah, I didn't even catch that. Yeah I fixed the typo, that seemed to do the trick but now a new problem arose. I can only click on "addbtn" once, before having to select a new tr then clicking the button again.

Comment: So why do you have the addbtn listener inside the tr listener?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148944/discussion-between-ziya-erkoc-and-j-doe43).